# Removing Null production from a CFG stored in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

My assignment is to make a program in C to remove null production from a CFG. Ans I can only use Linked List. Note that the Linked List value part points to an Array. I've given the output in the Code. My Null production removal is not working properly. Please run the code and tell me what you think and how can i improve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
/*the CFG
S>ABAC
A>aA|$
B>bB|$
C>c
*/
/*List produced  
    SABAC
    AaA
    A$
    BbB
    B$
    Cc*/
/*Desired Result
    SABAC
    SABC
    SBAC
    SBC
    AaA
    BbB
    Bb
    Cc*/
typedef struct node {
    struct node * next;
    //struct node * prev;
    char arr[7];//the array to save CFG per line
    }node_t;
char print_list(node_t * root);
//char first_set(node_t * root,char c);
char traversal(node_t * root);//To see which nodes have null productions
char rightTraversal(node_t * root,char);//Passing the nodes which have null production then removing them from list.
char c, temp, nonTerminal; int i=0; bool flag = true;
char null_list[7];
int null_counter = 0;


int main() {
    node_t * head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node_t * current = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node_t * root = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head = current;
    for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
        null_list[j] = '#';

    }

    FILE *fp;
    //char c, temp; int i=0; bool flag = true;
    fp = fopen("cfg.txt", "r");
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if(c == '\n') {
          current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
          //current->next->next = NULL;
          current = current->next;
          current->next = NULL;

          flag = true; i=0;
        }else if(c == '>' || c == ' '){continue;}
        else if(c == '|'){
            current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
            current = current->next;
            i = 0;
            current->arr[i] = temp;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
         else {
            current->arr[i] = c;
            i++;
            current->next = NULL;
            //current->prev = NULL;
            if(flag){
                temp = c;
                flag = false;
            }
           // continue;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    root = head;

   traversal(root);
     /*for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
         if(null_list[j] != '#'){
        printf("%c\n",null_list[j]);
         }
    }*/
   rightTraversal(root, null_list[0]);
   rightTraversal(root, null_list[1]); 
}
char print_list(node_t * root) {
    while(root->next != NULL){
        for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
            printf("%c", root->arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        root = root->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
char traversal(node_t * root) {
    while(root->next != NULL){
        for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
            if(root->arr[i] == '$'){
                null_list[null_counter] = root->arr[0];
                null_counter++;

            }
        }
        root = root->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
char rightTraversal(node_t * root, char c){
    node_t * shoot = root;
    while(shoot->next != NULL){
        for(int i=1; i<7; i++){
            if(shoot->arr[i] == c){
                node_t * temp_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                /*printf("%c\n", shoot->arr[0]);*/

                for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
                    temp_node->arr[i] = shoot->arr[i];
                }
                for(int k=1; k<7; k++){
                    if(temp_node->arr[k]==c){
                        temp_node->arr[k] = ' ';
                        break;
                    }   
                }
                temp_node->next = shoot->next;
                shoot->next = temp_node;
                break;
                //shoot->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                //shoot = shoot->next;
            }
        }
        shoot = shoot->next;
    }
        print_list(root);   
}
```

Comment: This is no debugging service! [ask], [mcve]

Comment: "*Please run the code and tell me what you think and how can i improve it.*" Why?

Answer (score 0):

[`fgetc()`](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.7.1) returns an `int`. You assign the result to a `char`.

So this condition

```
(c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
```

will never detect `EOF`.

To fix this defined `c` to be an `int` or introduce an intermediate `int` like this:

```
int ci;
while (ci = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
  c = ci;
```

If you'd pushed up the compiler's warning level to the maximum (`-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic` for GCC) it mostly like had warned you on this!